# How to make a gallery scroll vertically with a timer?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image]
Hi all, im trying to make this 3 gallery carousels that would have an automatic timer, switching from top to bottom, but up to a certain point, so no overflow.

How do I do this? as it's shown in the picture. the first and the third one are going at different pace, but both going down, and the middle one is going the opposite way from them, so bottom -up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch on website named https://codingnepalweb.com then search there "responsive carousel" then select what you want. The code is free to download.

However, instead of 3 vertical carousel, his video tutorial is 1 horizontal carousel. But you can modify it through making the flex-direction in "column". Then you need to copy and paste twice to make 3 carousels.

Then you need to select carousels and put on element that have a css named `justify-content: space-between`

Like this:

```html
<div class="Main>
  <!--- First Carousel --- >
  <!--- Second Carousel --- >
  <!--- Third Carousel --- >
<\div>
```

```css
.Main{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Then make sure that every carousel have a `flex-direction: column`, to make the carousel vertical.